# Query (column) that lacks a root node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am supposed to be extracting data from an XML column in sql server 2012. Some values for this column will have multiple nodes. Unfortunately, the XML does not have a root node, and so using the CROSS APPLY does not seem to work.

Simplified example:

```
<header><msg_type>TYPE_ONE</msg_type>
<status><status_1>aaaa</status_1><status_2>bbbb</status_2>
<node_1><customerID>1234</customerID><zipcode>11111</zipcode>...</node_1>
<node_2><customerID>1234</customerID><ordernum>12345</ordernum><data2>A</ordernum>...</node_2>
<node_2><customerID>1234</customerID><ordernum>34567></ordernum><data2>B</ordernum>...</node_2>
<node_3><customerID>1234</customerID><delivery>2014-05-05 14:00:00></delivery>...</node_3>
<node_1><customerID>ABCD</customerID><zipcode>12345</zipcode>...</node_1>
<node_2><customerID>ABCD</customerId><ordernum>123536</ordernum><data2>C</ordernum>...</node_2>
<node_3><customerID>ABCD</customerID><delivery>2014-05-05 16:00:00>...</node_3>
```

.
.
.

(... = more elements)

Here's an example using CROSS APPLY against one of the multi-node types:

```
select 
  t.InfoXML.value( '/node_1/customerID)[1]', 'varchar(50)' ) as CustomerId
  , CA.Det.value( '(/node_2/ordernum)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as OrderNumber
  , CA.Det.value( '(/node_2/data2)[1]', 'varchar(5)'  ) as Data2
from TableUnderTest as t
CROSS APPLY t.InfoXML.nodes( '/node_2') as CA(Det) 
where t.InfoXML.value( '(/header/msg_type)[1]', 'varchar(20)') = 'TYPE_ONE'
```

This had results

```
CustomerID    OrderNumber  Data2
================================
1234           12345       A
1234           12345       A
1234           12345       A
```

My current thought is to create a temporary table and insert the XML fields (that match the WHERE clause) after wrapping the XML value in a root node, and then trying to get the data from the temporary table. My current effort to set the first part up:

```
Declare @Rooted Table (Rec XML);
insert into @Rooted(Rec)
(
    select (convert (XML, '&lt;root&gt;', + convert(varchar(MAX),
    t.XmlData.query('./') + '&lt;\root&gt;')) as Rec
    from TableUnderTest t
    where t.XmlData.value( '(/header/msg_type)[1]', 'varchar(20)' ) = 'TYPE_ONE'
)
```

Right now, the above gives a syntax error.

What I want for output is something as follows:

```
CustomerID  ZipCode OrderNumber  Data2    Delivery          status2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1234         11111    12345     A       2014-05-05 14:00:00    aaaa    
1234         11111    34567     B       2014-05-05 14:00:00    aaaa
ABCD         12345    123456    D       2014-05-05 15:00:00    aaaa
```

What would be the best approach to take? (This is for testing, not production, so performance is not critical.) I've only been learning to write sql queries for XML for the last month, so perhaps I'm overlooking something. It appears the critical issue is the lack of a root node for the XML, but how do I work around it?

Comment: Could you proveide a valid XML data from which you want to get the desired output?